# Работа с хранимой процедурой в EF6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Использую базу MySQL. В базе есть хранимая процедура, в которой есть несколько запросов `select`, для выгрузки определенных порций данных. Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью Entity Framework обращаться к хранимой процедуре, и передавать параметры?

Comment: *как с помощью Entity Framework обращаться к хранимой процедуре* С этой стороны нет разницы между ХП, представлением и запросом. *и передавать параметры* И тут тоже.

Comment: @Akina, а можно вас привести простейший пример кода?

Comment: За примерами - к тем, кто работает на стороне EF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так

```
using(var db = new DbContext())
{
    var param = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@your_param_name", "your_value");
    var data= db.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityName>("YourStoredProcedureName @your_param_name", param);
    foreach (var d in data)
    {
       // Do something with your data
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за пример! Но, к сожалению, я не получаю нужного результата, хотя вызов хранимки в базе с тем же параметром отображает нужную информацию

Comment: `YourEntityName` очевидно нужно заменить подходящей сущностью. Не факт, что у вас такая есть. Что возвращает процедура, произвольный набор данных или типизированный?

Comment: `YourEntityName очевидно нужно заменить подходящей сущностью` - это понятно. Если вызываю другую процедуру (без параметров), все нормально отображается

Comment: повторю вопрос - что возвращает первая процедура? простое и наглядное решение - создать сущность, копирующую результат, возвращаемый процедурой

Comment: Все, нашел свою ошибку. Вам спасибо за помощь